# Why doesn't Pycharm show dictionary methods in this case?

Tags: python, dictionary, pycharm

I am trying to do a very simple service to collect and print data from a RESTfull API, in Python.
This is the code I have:

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get("url")
data2 = response.json()
print type(data2)
```

Here is my issue: when I print data2 type, it tells me it's a dictionary, so when I do `data2.` (notice the dot) my IDE should give me a series of methods like len(), cmp(),str() for me to choose from. But nothing shows up.
 The same thing happens to me using Atom.
 To be clear, if I write `data2.len()`, it does not say it is an error, so it recognizes the methods. But it doesn't show them as a suggestion.

How should I solve this? Thank you so much.

Comment: pycharm does not know data2 is a dict because requests does not declare a return type. When you print it, the type is evaluated at runtime. the IDE needs static types. If you type `data2 = dict()`, or `variable = []`, then you will have your completion.

Comment: @njzk2, Thank you for your answer. I tried what you suggested. If I do `data2=[]` and then try `data2(dot)` before `data2=response.json()`, all the methods show up. However, if I do it after, it doesn't work.

Comment: yeah, because at this point the reference has changed, and pycharm *can't*  know the type. there is nothing you can do, here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm's inability to display the methods you mention indicate inability to infer the variable's type from the code alone. Which often indicates that the code might not be prepared to handle that variable's data properly in all cases (in many cases that means buggy code).

The fact that your code prints the type as `dict` in *that particular execution* doesn't mean it'll *always* be a `dict` (otherwise PyCharm would have been able to infer the type).

Making the code better prepared to deal with the variable's data in any situation - will make the type inferable, which will also allow PyCharm to fill in the data correctly.

For example, you could write your code like this:

```
response = requests.get("url")
data2 = response.json()
assert isinstance(data2, dict)
print type(data2)  # here data2's methods would be listed
```

or,

```
response = requests.get("url")
data2 = response.json()
if isinstance(data2, dict):
    print type(data2)  # here data2's methods would be listed
```

Answer (score 2):

As it was mentioned in comments PyCharm doesn't know type because `requests` doesn't declare return type. But it's possible to use type comments here (see [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-comments)):

```
response = requests.get("url")
data2 = response.json()  # type: dict
print(type(data2))
```